# OWL DL Query on Symmetric property

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, protege

I'm trying to put together a small ontology (class HP, class HEWLETT_PACKARD linked together by a symmetric property). The Owl is below. What I want to do is query in Protege "equal_symmetric only hp" or "equal_symmetric only hewlett_packard" and get the opposing company. Essentially I want to get synonyms for each company's name.

```xml
    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="ontologies/2014/1/untitled-ontology-2#equal_symmetric">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;SymmetricProperty"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="ontologies/2014/1/untitled-ontology-2#hewlett_packard">
        <owl:equivalentClass>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="ontologies/2014/1/untitled-ontology-2#equal_symmetric"/>
                <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="ontologies/2014/1/untitled-ontology-2#hp"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:equivalentClass>        
    </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="ontologies/2014/1/untitled-ontology-2#hp">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="ontologies/2014/1/untitled-ontology-2#brand"/>
    </owl:Class>
```

Comment: As a general note, StackOverflow isn't a forum, so while it might seem strange at first, there's no need for some of the "pleasantries" that we'd often use in emails, boards, etc., such as signatures and thanks.  I've edited them out this time.   Similarly, I removed "any suggestions appreciated", because StackOverflow questions tend to be nice and focused on a particular problem;  open ended things don't fare so well.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?  If they're classes, you can declare that HEWLETT_PACKARD and HP are equivalent classes.  If you have individuals, you can declare that they are owl:sameAs each other.  What you're doing with the allValuesFrom restriction is less clear.  What is says is that the class hewlett_packard is equivalent to "the class of things such that any value they have for the property equal_symmetric must be an hp."  I don't really see the utility there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two classes and you're trying to say that they're the same, you should probably just use an equivalent class axiom.  In Protégé and RDF/XML it would look like this:

[image]

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns="http://stackoverflow.com/q/22047101/1281433/ontology#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/22047101/1281433/ontology"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/22047101/1281433/ontology#HEWLETT_PACKARD">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
      <owl:Class rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/22047101/1281433/ontology#HP"/>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
  </owl:Class>
</rdf:RDF>
```

If you use the DL query, you can see the equivalent classes:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Joshua. I'm now on the right track. I was under the impression that equivalence HAD to be established through a property but I see now that it doesn't. Thanks again.

Comment: @mj_ On the contrary;  if you want two classes to be equivalent, you'll typically assert that they are.  If you end up making two classes equivalent via various axioms, it's a sign that you might have missed something.  (Not always, but often.)